# Objective-C: How to get the UIPopoverPresentationController arrow to point up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, constraints, uipopovercontroller

I have implemented a `UIPopoverPresentationController` for an iPad app, but the arrow for the popover points down instead of up. The `popPresenter.arrowDirection` gives an error saying that is a read-only property. How can I set the arrow for the popOver to point up instead of down?

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [self.alertController popoverPresentationController];
popPresenter.sourceView =  self;       
popPresenter.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.center.x, self.contentSize.height, self.bounds.origin.y, self.contentSize.height);
popPresenter.arrowDirection = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
```

Comment: You want to set the `permittedArrowDirections` property

Comment: I set the `permittedArrowDirections` property to equal `YES`? But then the `arrowDirectionProperty` is still read-only...

Comment: @matt what I was being told, wasn't very clear or a full answer...

Comment: @D.Khan `permittedArrowDirections` is not a BOOL , you cant set it to YES

Comment: Yeah I got that already from the answer below. However my problem still remains, the arrow is not pointing up and the popOver is messed up when I set the property to `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
popPresenter.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that messed up the entire pop-over view, and stretched the constraints and made it look all wonky.

Comment: **From Apple Docs** Prior to displaying the popover, set this property to the arrow directions that you prefer for your popover. During presentation, the popover presentation controller tries to respect your preferences but may use a different arrow direction if it cannot otherwise lay out the popover. The actual arrow direction in use by the popover is stored in the arrowDirection property.

Answer (score 0):

Following code tells iOS to present UIPopoverPresentationController with arrow pointing upwards

```
popPresenter.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
```

But if you read apple doc related to it (And also the name implies it) that it only tells OS to try and have arrow pointed up, its not guaranteed.

[permittedArrowDirections](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622319-permittedarrowdirections?language=objc)

> Prior to displaying the popover, set this property to the arrow
>   directions that you prefer for your popover. During presentation, the
>   popover presentation controller tries to respect your preferences but
>   may use a different arrow direction if it cannot otherwise lay out the
>   popover. The actual arrow direction in use by the popover is stored in
>   the arrowDirection property.

You need to present your popover where there is enough space for popover to show up with arrow pointed upwards and have proper UI.